# Aggregate function in Group By Clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use to use the following group by query to remove redundant transactions (de dupe):

```
SELECT
    optimized_transaction_date,
    cobrand_id,
    merchant_name,
    Description,
    UNIQUE_MEM_ID,
    Amount,
    distinct_count as members,

    into   xx
    FROM yy
    WHERE xx)



GROUP BY optimized_transaction_date ,
        cobrand_id ,
        merchant_name,
        Description ,
        UNIQUE_MEM_ID ,
        Amount,
        members
```

However I added some aggregate functions I would like to apply:

```
SELECT
    optimized_transaction_date,
    cobrand_id,
    merchant_name,
    Description,
    UNIQUE_MEM_ID,
    Amount,
    distinct_count as members,
    Amount/members as calc,
    cast(count(amount) as DOUBLE PRECISION)/members as count


    into   xx
    FROM yy
    WHERE xx)


    GROUP BY optimized_transaction_date ,
            cobrand_id ,
            merchant_name,
            Description ,
            UNIQUE_MEM_ID ,
            Amount, 
            members
            calc
```

The problem is calc and especially count are now returning sums/counts that include redundant transactions.  For example, the count field will return a value x2 other rows when there is a duplicate transaction.  How do I write my query so that it only returns calc/count POST the group by (de-duped for duplicate transactions).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Normally is not possible the use of alias in group by  (https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/7608.1259177709%40sss.pgh.pa.us) 
so you could repeat the orginal value

```
SELECT
    optimized_transaction_date,
    cobrand_id,
    merchant_name,
    Description,
    UNIQUE_MEM_ID,
    Amount,
    distinct_count as members,
    Amount/members as calc,
    cast(count(amount) as DOUBLE PRECISION)/members as count


    into   xx
    FROM yy
    WHERE xx)


    GROUP BY optimized_transaction_date ,
            cobrand_id ,
            merchant_name,
            Description ,
            UNIQUE_MEM_ID ,
            Amount, 
            distinct_count
            (Amount/distinct_count)
```